Processor SDK Linux Default Image on BeagleY-Ai cannot Boot
I am trying to install TI Linux SDK and its SD Card image named tisdk-edgeai-image-j722s-evm.wic.xz for AM67A processor provided from TI on the BeagleY-Ai evaluation board. The board doesn't boot.
I wrote that image to SD card with Rufus and insert it into the board, but it doesn't boot and board doesn't open. I can't connect via terminal with ssh. The LED on board that should blink to indicate booting remains fixed as red. I tried the v09x and v10x versions of the that image, the result didn't change.
The Debian image provided by BeagleBoard opens without any problems by following the same steps.
How can tisdk-edgeai-image-j722s-evm.wic.xz image boot on BeagleY-Ai? I will asked this because I am inexperienced: There is no EMMC on the board. Can be U-Boot need to be running on EMMC to load this image?

How to write a disk image or make a board boot it isn't really about electrical engineering, but using the tools to write an image or making the product boot it.

alpd4 - Hi, As there is no electronics nor low-level firmware programming part of the question, I don't see it was being on-topic here. I found that you've asked the same question on the TI E2E forums. That looks a more suitable place to ask. || Please see the [tour] & [help] for this SE site, as they differ from typical forums. Not everything that involves using electronics is on-topic here.

are you certain that the image runs on the board? ... maybe it is supposed to be installed on a PC

@SamGibson you are right. Just, I found similar posts so I thought it would be appropriate to share them here. I will check out the links you provided.
